# Give 754 linux file permission to java application log files generated through Spring Logback

Tags: java, logback, spring-logback

In my Java Spring-based application, using Logback to generate application logs, I need to give specific `754` linux file permission to log files generated by this application.

How can specific file permissions of log files be set in `logback-spring.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can change application user file creation mask by `umask 023` in linux (best to do it on startup).

If you want to have more control over it inside application you can upgrade your logging to Log4j2 which is more powerful and starting from version `2.9` you can set it in `log4j2.xml`, i.e. `<RollingFile ... filePermissions="rwxr-xr--">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this to your pom file:

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -DUMASK="0022"
                        -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK="0022"
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```